# Contact form validation in php

Tags: php

```
<?php

$name_error = $email_error = $phone_error = $url_error = $last_name_error= "";
$firstName = $lastName = $email = $phone = $message = $url = $success = "";

if (isset($_POST["sendMessage"])) {
    if (empty($_POST["firstName"])) {
        $name_error = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstName)) {
            $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["lastName"])) {
        $last_name_error = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $lastName = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastName)) {
            $last_name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email_error = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $email_error = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
        $phone_error = "Phone is required";
    } else {
        $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
            $phone_error = "Invalid phone number";
        }
    }


    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $message = "";
    } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    }

    if ($name_error == '' and $last_name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' ){
        $message_body = '';
        unset($_POST['sendMessage']);
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
        }

        $to = 'some@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'webmaster@example.com';
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message)){
            $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
            $firstName = $lastName = $email = $phone = $message = '';
        }
    }

}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

?>
```

I tried to make this contact form validated. but it doesn't work. whenever i send a email form live server only message is send but name, phone, email don't send. please someone help me. I am working on it since last day but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you're not sending them at all. Look at your code:

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $message)){
```

Yoou're sending the variable $message as message, thats fine.. but, lets have a look whats inside this variable:

```
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $message = "";
    } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    }
```

You're assigning the value of `$_POST["message"]` to it - nothing else.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
        }
```

I think you would send $message_body instead of $message, then it should work fine :)

Hope it help.

Comment: ok i am trying now to chg this. but if i give wrong name, number or email it doesn't show any message. please answer about this problem

Comment: Why it should? You've only a `IF` condition if everything is fine, you send the e-mail.. no `else` condition. You've to make a `else` and then simply `echo` the error messages

Comment: isn't he suppose to send `$message_body`?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile My last sentence in my answer: `I think you would send $message_body instead of $message, then it should work fine :)` so yes, he is.